# Error using Httrack for download a blog from a blogger site

Tags: download, blogging

I am traying to donwload one my blogs using Httrack. Every time I tried I got this error message:

```
**MIRROR ERROR!**
```

`HTTrack has detected that the current mirror is empty. If it was an update, the previous mirror has been restored. Reason: the first page(s) either could not be found, or a connection problem occured. 
=> Ensure that the website still exist, and/or check your proxy setting! <=`

I think may be is not possible to download any blog from blogger with this problem.

Does anyone know how to donwload a blog with this program?
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to buggy `httrack`, why not use `wget`?

```
domain="theravingrick.blogspot.com"
wget -e robots=off -r --no-parent --reject "search?*" "http://${domain}"
find "$domain" -type f -exec sed -i "s/http:\/\/${domain}\///g" {} \;
```